# Error in executing MySQL query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert data to MySQL table, but i got exception message which say:

```
Apr 16, 2012 3:01:03 PM RFID.RFID passDetInput
SEVERE: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:436)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1390)
at RFID.RFID.passDetInput(RFID.java:495)
at RFID.RFID.SaveActionPerformed(RFID.java:472)
at RFID.RFID.access$700(RFID.java:28)
at RFID.RFID$7.actionPerformed(RFID.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    ...
```

This is my code to do the data manipulation:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public void passDetInput(String tag, String fname, String lname, String pID, String ConNo, String phone) {

        String SQLcomm = "insert into pass_det (RFID_tag, fname, lname, ID_num, Conveyor_num, Phone_num) values (/'"+tag+"/',/'"+fname+"/',/'"+lname+"/',/'"+pID+"/',/'"+ConNo+"/',/'"+phone+"/')";

        java.sql.Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/passenger_details";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(SQLcomm);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(RFID.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

and the function is executed via button-press.

I've check the database name, table name, and elements name, and they're all correct.
Where's the mistake in my code?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: This is a clear explanation in your exception stack trace "*Can not issue data manipulation statements with `executeQuery()`*" means that you can not use data manipulation statements such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` with `executeQuery()`. You must use them with `executeUpdate()` and `executeQuery()` with a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `execute()` or `executeUpdate()` method. If I remember correctly, `executeQuery` is only for `SELECT` statements.

Also you should look at: `PreparedStatement`

Comment: when using that command, i got this error, i.imgur.com/83iOe.png it's weird since it's a String but recognized as int

Answer (score 2):

You should use `st.executeUpdate(SQLcomm)`;

Comment: when using that command, i got this error,
http://i.imgur.com/83iOe.png

it's weird since it's a String but recognized as int

Comment: @Firhan Fikrin:) `executeUpdate()` returns an `int` value. You need to assign it to an `int` variable. You're currently assigning it to `rs` of type `ResultSet`. You can just avoid it, if you don't need the return value like `st.executeUpdate("Your SQL Query")`. Don't assign it. It just returns a status value of `executeUpdate()` whether it succeeds or not.

Comment: Something like this `int temp=st.executeUpdate("Your SQL Query")` or just `st.executeUpdate("Your SQL Query")`, if you don't want the return value, just avoid assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @Firhan Fikrin:) You're inserting (or deleting or updating) data into a database table and hence, you're not retrieving any `ResultSet` from the database and you just need something like this `int temp=executeUpdate("Your SQL Query")` statement. If you retrieve data from the database using a `SELECT` query, you need `rs=executeQuery("Your SQL Query")` because you're retrieving a `ResultSet` from the database that you need to assign to a `ResultSet`. Just that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Only `executeUpload()` will solve your problem.

Comment: That's a pretty minimalist answer. I think the person asking the question might want a little more information than that.